Proj and affine base change: find canonical morphisms from Proj of a graded ring
This is Vakil's FOAG (ed. july 2023), exercise 17.2.A. Suppose $A \to B$ is a map of rings and $S$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$-graded ring over $A$. I am trying to find a canonical isomorphism
$$\operatorname{Proj}(S \otimes_A B) \simeq (\operatorname{Proj} S) \times_{\operatorname{Spec} A} \operatorname{Spec} B.$$
My strategy is to first find two morphisms from the Proj of the tensor product: one into the Proj of S, and one into the Spec of B. Then I would like to show that these morphisms have the universal property of the fiber product over $\operatorname{Spec} A$. I need help finding the second morhism. For the first, I know that for a general $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$-graded ring $T$, there is a canonical morphism of schemes $\operatorname{Proj} T \to \operatorname{Spec} T_0$. In my case, this gives a canonical morphism of schemes $\operatorname{Proj} (S \otimes_A B) \to \operatorname{Spec} B$.
However for the second morphism, I am stuck. Is it legitimate to put a trivial grading on $S \otimes_A B$ (where everything has degree 0, and degree $d>0$ forms are all zero)? Then I would get some $\operatorname{Proj} (S \otimes_A B) \to \operatorname{Spec} (S \otimes_A B) \to \operatorname{Spec} S$, with the last morphism induced by the canonical injection $S \to S \otimes_A B$. Then I would need to show that I can corestrict the composition to get a morphism $\operatorname{Proj}(S \otimes_A B) \to \operatorname{Proj} S$, and I would need this morphism to agree with the first one over $\operatorname{Spec} A$. Does this work and/or am I overcomplicating things?

So the grading on $S\otimes_A B$ is simply $\deg(s \otimes b) = \deg s$ i.e. the $B$ has trivial grading. For the question, I think the best way is to work affine-locally.

No, that's not legitimate. What you want to do is use the map $S = S\otimes_A A \to S\otimes_A B$ induced from applying $S\otimes_A-$ to the map $A\to B$. This is graded since tensor products commute with direct sums, so this sends $S_+$ to $(S\otimes_A B)_+$, and therefore it induces an actual map of Projs by exercise 7.4.A. This map will do what you want - if you run in to issues checking, please leave a comment here.
